# How to add conditional force to the command in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to copy the file forcedly only for `projectA` item from below playbook.

```
- name: Populate /usr/local/mywork/ binaries where necessary
  copy:
    src: "output/here/usr/local/mywork/{{item}}"
    dest: "/usr/local/mywork/{{ item }}"
    force: '{{ item == "projectA" }}'
  with_items: "{{ server_files }}"
```

I added `force: '{{ item == "projectA" }}'`.

But it's not working.
Some part is not correct?

Comment: The play should work as expected. Make sure you understand how *force* works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── files
│   ├── projectA
│   ├── projectB
│   └── projectC
└── mywork
    ├── projectA
    ├── projectB
    └── projectC

2 directories, 6 files
```

The content of the files differs

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/files/*
1
1
1

shell> cat /tmp/test/mywork/*
0
0
0
```

The option [*force*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-force):

- If true, the remote file will be replaced when the contents are different than the source.
- If false, the file will only be transferred if the destination does not exist.

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    server_files: [projectA, projectB, projectC]
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: "/tmp/test/files/{{ item }}"
        dest: "/tmp/test/mywork/{{ item }}"
        force: "{{ item == 'projectA' }}"
      loop: "{{ server_files }}"
```

works as expected and copies only the file *projectA*. Running the play in the *--check --diff* mode gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/test/mywork/projectA
+++ after: /tmp/test/files/projectA
@@ -1 +1 @@
-0
+1

changed: [localhost] => (item=projectA)
ok: [localhost] => (item=projectB)
ok: [localhost] => (item=projectC)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

There will be no changes if the content of the files *projectA* is the same

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/files/projectA
1
shell> cat /tmp/test/mywork/projectA
1
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=projectA)
ok: [localhost] => (item=projectB)
ok: [localhost] => (item=projectC)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```